# Let $F$ be a gradient field. Prove that if $fF$ is conservative, then $f$ has the same level surfaces as a potential for $F$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields

Let $F = \nabla\phi$ where $\phi \in C^2(\mathbb R^3)$ and let $f:\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R$ be a $C^1$ function. Prove that if $fF$ is a conservative field then $f$ is constant over the level surfaces of $\phi$

Here's what I got so far: $fF$ being a conservative field means its curl is $0$. Since $F$ is conservative itself the curl is reduced to $\nabla f \times F = \nabla f \times \nabla \phi = 0$

This last fact can be expressed by the equality $\nabla f(x) = k(x)\nabla \phi(x)$ for some scalar function $k$, if the gradient of $\phi$ never vanishes

This already intuitively tells me the answer: Since level surfaces (when smooth) are perpendicular to the gradient, and since both gradients are parallel, then the level surfaces must be the same.

Now I can actually prove the statement *provided the level surfaces for $\phi$ are smooth*. If the level surfaces are smooth I can parametrize any curve by a $C^1$ function $T:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^3$

Then all I need to prove is that $f \circ T$ is constant, or that $\nabla(f \circ T) = 0$

But since both $f$ and $T$ are differentiable I get

$$\nabla(f \circ T) = (\nabla f \circ T) \cdot DT = (k \circ T)(\nabla \phi \circ T) \cdot DT = (k \circ T)\nabla(\phi \circ T) = 0$$

The last step is equal to $0$ because $T$ parametrized a level curve of $\phi$ so $\phi \circ T$ is constant

The problem is that it's not always true that the level surfaces will be smooth. This is only true if $\nabla \phi$ is never $0$.

What can I do to prove this in the general case? (i.e $\nabla \phi$ is allowed to be $0$)?

Comment: You have to be a lot more specific about how you allow $\nabla\phi$ to be $0$. What if it happens on a set with non-empty interior? But if you really are getting a foliation with the level sets of $\phi$, then the phenomenon is modeled by something like $\phi(x,y)=\frac 12 y^2$ in $\Bbb R^2$. You find that $\partial f/\partial x = 0$ whenever $y\ne 0$, but then by continuity, you must have $\partial f/\partial x = 0$ everywhere.

Comment: I have no idea. This question was on an exam years ago and it's supposed to hold for any $C^2$ function $\phi$

Comment: Well, it doesn’t. You can easily give a counterexample if $\phi$ vanishes on a ball.

Comment: Can you lay it down for me? What happens when it vanishes on a ball?

Comment: I'm guessing f need not be constant on said ball?

Comment: Right! $f$ can be arbitrary on a smaller ball !